# Adb Detects More Than One Devices When Connected to Devices Over WiFi React Native

Tags: android, adb, react-native

I am working with React Native, Everything works fine with USB Cable but when I try to debug my app on the physical android device using WiFi it always fail with error saying `More Than One Devices` but I only have one device attached. I have confirm it using `adb devices` command, there is always one device.
I have tried with two android phones but same results.
I have tried all the solutions available but nothing works.

OS : Windows 10 
React Native : >0.60 
Android OS : 8.1 Nougat

Steps I have Followed.
Connected to Physical Device using `adb connect 192.168.10.5`
Try to See Device Connected with `adb devices` and I have connected device 192.168.10.5:5555
Run the App using `react-native run-android` which opens package bundler and app on the device but nothing works after `done loading dependencies graph`.

Comment: Run commands:
 adb kill-server 
and adb start-server

Comment: I already have done that but it also didn't work.

Comment: If you are using adb wifi then disconnect cable while running app

Comment: I always test after disconnecting USB cable

Answer (score 0):

Then you can specify your device id through --deviceId

`react-native run-android --deviceId=DEVICE_ID`

You will get deviceId when you run `adb devices`

Comment: same error adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator